# react-json-schema tutorial does not show up in browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I am completely new to web development (html/js) but would now like to use the react-json-schema package which works great in the provided sandbox.

However, I can't even get the tutorial to work. I have written an html, as given in the tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/jsx" src="react.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the corresponding javascript file "react.js":

```
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Test form",
  type: "string"
};

ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

However, the schema simply does not show up in a browser when opening the html. There is no error message.

Things I have tried:

1.) importing the scripts from the cdn, so adding these lines in the html head:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@rjsf/core/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
```

2.) re-installing npm and the react-json-schema, react and react-dom packages both locally and globally

3.) importing said packages in the js:

```
import react from React
import import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Form from "@rjsf/core";
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
import Form from 'react-jsonschema-form';
class Index extends DataComponent{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
      schema: {
            type: 'object',
            title: 'Info',
            properties: {
                task: {
                    type: 'string',
                    title: 'First Name'
                }
            }
      }
    }
  }
  render(){
   return(
    <Form 
     schema={this.state.schema}
    />
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: it still does not display anything even if I paste this right into a <script> in the html. IDE tells me for constructor(): Missed superclass's constructor invocation

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the library then remove

//const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;